# With TikZ, is it possible to split a node horizontally and vertically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

With TikZ, is it possible to split a node horizontally *and* vertically?

What I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={draw, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt}]
    \node [rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=3]
        {Services
         \nodepart{two} Event Driven Framework
         \nodepart{three} OS Adapter Layer};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is:

```
/----------+------------------------\
|          | Event Driven Framework |
| Services +------------------------+
|          |    OS Adapter Layer    |
\----------+------------------------/
```

Comment: I don't think you can. You can put three nodes and then draw the lines.

Comment: You can define a `pic` with the required structure, if you plan to reuse that kind of "shape"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible out of the box. But you can draw the individual `node`s and then draw the lines. Even better, as per JLDiaz's idea, you can put it as a `pic`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit}

\tikzset{
    pics/vhsplit/.style n args = {3}{
        code = {
        \node[text width=2cm] (A) at (0,0) {#1};  
        \node[anchor=south west,text width=2cm] (B) at (A.east) {#2};
        \node[anchor=north west,text width=2cm] (C) at (A.east){#3};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,rounded corners,fit=(A)(B)(C)] {}; 
        \draw (B.north west) -- (C.south west)
              (B.south west) -- (C.north east);    
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[every node/.append style={draw, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt}]
    \path pic (a) {vhsplit={Some}{Text}{comes here}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising. However, I am getting `Use of \tikz@parabola doesn't match its definition.` My pgf version is: 2.10.

Comment: Is my pgf version too old?

Comment: @sergej `pic` is a version 3 feature. :(. Please update. Or else you have to hard code each such node.

Comment: I see. Many Thanks! I am going to hard code the node as I need it only once.

Answer (score 6):

I am posting this as a matter of record. I had to solve a very similar problem which allowed for text of arbitrary length in all three fields, particularly on the left. There are some extras in this code merely to show the possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newsavebox{\linetmp}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.multipart,positioning}

\NewDocumentCommand{\threepart}{mmm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (L) {%
        \sbox{\linetmp}{#1}%
        \ifdim\wd\linetmp<2in%% Fit on one line?
            \bfseries\centering#1
        \else
            \parbox{2in}{\rightskip0pt plus 3em\strut#1\strut}
        \fi
    };
    \node[rounded corners,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        text width=2in,
        align=center,
        right= 0pt of L.east] (R) {%
            \bfseries\strut#2\strut
            \nodepart{two}\itshape\strut#3\strut};
    \draw[thick]  (R.text split east) -- (R.text split west);
    \node[inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        thick,
        rounded corners,
        fit=(L)(R)] (W) {};
    \draw[thick] (W.south west -| R.west) -- (W.north west -| R.west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\threepart{Services}{Event Driven Framework}{OS Adapter Layer}

\bigskip

\noindent
\threepart{Some very long text in the left field}{Some very long text in the upper right field}{Some very long text in the lower right field}

\end{document}
```

[image: three part "node" example]