Defining anchor points in a custom pic
There are possibly very useful answers in this post, but I couldn't understand them.
In the example below, how can I define an anchor at north of my pic so that while drawing a line from that point, I do not need to do manual calculations to work out its coordinate, or I may want to work with a different size of that shape, etc.? (I know for this simple example I could have done it with circle node shape and use the predefined anchors; the example below is as such for the sake of simplicity.)

\documentclass[border=2pc]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\tikzset{
 pulley/.pic={
    code={
\draw[very thick] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) pic{pulley};
\draw[very thick] (0,10pt)--++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The established approach to this is to define coordinates with names that start with a hyphen inside the code for the .pic (such as (-north)). Once you name a \pic in your code (for example (A)), you can then refer to these coordinates by just concatenating the name of the pic and the coordinate (here: (A-north)).
\documentclass[border=1pc]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pulley/.pic={
        code={
            \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
            \coordinate (-north) at (0,10pt);
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) pic (A) {pulley};
    \draw[very thick] (A-north) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you. Is it possible to approach it more systematically, so that, say, if I were to use a different size of the shape, things take care of themselves?

@blackened What do you mean? Try \draw (0,0) pic[scale=2] (A) {pulley}; for example. The anchor will shift to where it belongs.

@blackened I found thiS helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705474/getting-pics-to-act-like-a-chain
